# Best way to structure an EF code first application, so that it can work with enums and TSQL code side nicely

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I am looking for a better way to structure my application so that I can work with enums using entity framework, and cases where I would need to use TSQL eg stored procs ,common table expressions etc.It looks great to use it on the linq to Entities side , but on the TSQL side it does not look that nice eg when projecting the results and you want the enum string values.I have already looked at the EF enum support tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx) and other examples from the web and on SO and I just cant seem to find a standard way

Part of the code from the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx)

```
public enum DepartmentNames
{
  English,
  Math,
  Economics
}    

public partial class Department
{
  public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
  public DepartmentNames Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Budget { get; set; }
}
```

**My list of questions are:**

- how to deal with enums in case of **stored procs** or **common table expressions**, or anything requiring TSQL, rather than linq to Entities
- suppose I create a class for EF to store the enum values,is it best practice to have an equivalent table in my database for the enum, by creating an equivalent class like in the code below, and manualy adding the State1 ,State2 values in the EF seeding process  etc.
- following above ,what is the best way to name + structure the enum ,like you can see from the code

for example

```
public class SomeStateType
{
    public int SomeStateTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public enum Type
    {
        State1 = 1,
        State2 = 2,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some Enums in my code.

## Some things:

- Enums are not strings. The example above `English, Math, Economics` represents the numbers `0,1,2` respectively.
- I checked my DB and I could not found the Enums, so I guess EF does not create a Table for them (I might be wrong, though)
- When you create a Enum, the type is your Enum, just like the example above. In your case, it will be: `public Type *name of your property*`

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, enums are fine on the linq to entities side of things but not on the sql code(when you need to do someting a bit more complex, I have had that stiuation before) eg stored proc ,common table expressions etc, it will be not be elagent to show the results of the sql statement with enums as string

Answer (score 1):

In the example, the integer values of the enumeration are stored in the database, not the string.  EF maps the integer values to your enumeration values.
Personally I prefer explicitly number each value of the enumeration, as you have, but not nest the enumeration within db model class - the reason being that you presumably want to be able to use the enumeration elsewhere to examine the "state" of your db objects.

```
//Model
public class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public CourseTypes CourseType { get; set; }
    //stuff omitted
}

public enum CourseTypes
{
    [Description("Training")]
    Training = 1,
    [Description("Awareness Only")]
    AwarenessOnly = 2
    //etc
}
```

And I use a helper method (which I found on SO, but don't have the link to properly credit, sorry) to grab the description attribute of the enums so that I can have a presentable string if required, rather than a name property.

```
public static string GetEnumDescription<TEnum>(TEnum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if ((attributes != null) && (attributes.Length > 0))
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,I was thinking of having CourseTypes enum as a table by itself..reason being when not using Linq to Entities eg a stored proc  with a join to CourseTypes  sql statement  ,with the result showing a bunch of rows with enum values as strings.